# SQL sequence numbers and start/end date analysis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL (SQL Management Studio 2016) and I only joined the site this morning...so my first post! I have been looking for a solution on the site regarding my issue. I have found a few links but none that (I think) will work having tried a few. I have a table that holds boiler service data. One address can have multiple dates/sequence numbers. I am looking to create a script that proves the latest sequential numbers start date is less than or equal to the latest sequential end date. So, in my example,  I'd want to select the MAX seq_no for the start_date field and the 2nd MAX seq_no for the end_date field to make sure they haven't breached timescale.

My sample data has been added as an image (hopefully!)...just two addresses but there are 1000's in reality):

I have tried SLQ to get max seq_no's for just the end date initially but it just keeps bringing back all the entries:

```
select max (seq_no) as SEQNO, end_date, cmpnt_ref, prty_id
FROM hgmpcych
where prty_id in ('ABBEY10_TD12','ABBEY12_TD12') and  cmpnt_ref='Boiler' and cycle_no='5'
group by end_date,prty_id,cmpnt_ref,seq_no
order by prty_id
```

This will probably be quite basic, but I am still pretty new to SQL. Any hints, advice or tips would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my SQL didn't paste prroperly: select max (seq_no) as SEQNO, end_date, cmpnt_ref, prty_id
  FROM hgmpcych
  where prty_id in ('ABBEY10_TD12','ABBEY12_TD12') and  cmpnt_ref='DOM_GAS_BOIL' and cycle_no='5'
 group by end_date,prty_id,cmpnt_ref,seq_no
 order by prty_id

Comment: Don't bother about that image, people here want formatted text instead!

Comment: Please also include the results that you expect from that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to mark the rows in each group and only select the rows marked with 1 or 2 (The two "latest" rows)...

```
WITH
  enumerated_hgmpcych AS
(
  SELECT
    seq_no, start_date, end_date, cmpnt_ref, prty_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prty_id, cmpnt_ref
                           ORDER BY seq_no DESC
                      )
                        desc_seq_enumerator
  FROM
    hgmpcych
  WHERE
        prty_id in ('ABBEY10_TD12','ABBEY12_TD12')
    AND cmpnt_ref='Boiler'
    AND cycle_no='5'
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  enumerated_hgmpcych
WHERE
  desc_seq_enumerator <= 2
ORDER BY
  prty_id,
  cmpnt_ref,
  seq_no
```

If you wanted to, you could collapse that to one row per group...

```
WITH
  enumerated_hgmpcych AS
(
  SELECT
    seq_no, start_date, end_date, cmpnt_ref, prty_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY prty_id, cmpnt_ref
                           ORDER BY seq_no DESC
                      )
                        desc_seq_enumerator
  FROM
    hgmpcych
  WHERE
        prty_id in ('ABBEY10_TD12','ABBEY12_TD12')
    AND cmpnt_ref='Boiler'
    AND cycle_no='5'
)
SELECT
  prty_id,
  cmpnt_ref,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 1 THEN seq_no     END)   AS final_seq_no,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 1 THEN start_date END)   AS final_start_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 1 THEN end_date   END)   AS final_end_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 2 THEN seq_no     END)   AS prev_seq_no,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 2 THEN start_date END)   AS prev_start_date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN desc_seq_enumerator = 2 THEN end_date   END)   AS prev_end_date
FROM
  enumerated_hgmpcych
WHERE
  desc_seq_enumerator <= 2
GROUP BY
  prty_id,
  cmpnt_ref
ORDER BY
  prty_id,
  cmpnt_ref
```

Comment: That seems to have produced exactly what I was looking for MatBailie, many thanks for your excellent help!

Comment: @NuToSQL - Feel free to upvote any answers that helped, and accept the most helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `max(seq_no)`, then you don't want it in the `group by`:

```
select max (seq_no) as SEQNO, end_date, cmpnt_ref, prty_id
from hgmpcych
where prty_id in ('ABBEY10_TD12', 'ABBEY12_TD12') and
      cmpnt_ref = 'Boiler' and cycle_no = '5'
group by end_date, prty_id, cmpnt_ref
order by prty_id;
```